# How to set and use constants in rsyslog (RainerScript)?

Tags: rsyslog

I'm writing an application which includes an rsyslog configuration which gets placed in `/etc/rsyslog.d/`.

Certain logmessages should be redirected to a named pipe, like so:

```
template (name="my_fmt" type="string" string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg%\n")
if ( ... ) then {
    action(type="ompipe" Pipe="/tmp/SITENAME/pipe" Template="my_fmt")
    stop
}
```

This works as intended. Unfortunately, the SITENAME in the above pipe's name is not known in advance and must be configured by the customer.

I could write instructions like *"find any occurence of the word SITENAME in the file and replace it with your particular $sitename"* or even deliver an `sed` command, but I don't like that approach. Instead, I'd like to set a constant at the beginning of the file and use it wherever need is. Like so:

```
set ACTUAL_SITE = "foo";

template (name="my_fmt" type="string" string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg%\n")
if ( ... ) then {
    action(type="ompipe" Pipe="/tmp/$ACTUAL_SITE/pipe" Template="my_fmt")
    stop
}
```

How can I do this? I (think I) tried all variants of `$`, `%…%` and `%$…%` in the `Pipe="…"` part but none worked. The value of `ACTUAL_SITE` never changes after initial installation. I just want to simplify the configuration for the customer and say *"set the value of ACTUAL_SITE to your actual site's name"* and not make him fiddling around with the rest of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outdated `rsyslog` versions (8.32 and lower) do not support what you try to do.

In current rsyslog versions, you can do this via backticks constants, see [**here**](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/constant_strings.html).

To do so:

- define an environment variable (or write a file) before rsyslog startup, usually by adding it to the startup script upon install on the target machine. Let's call this SITE_PIPE and do as follows:

  ```
  export SITEPIPE="/tmp/mysite/pipe"
  ```
- then, use backticks as such:

  ```
  action(type="ompipe" Pipe=`echo $SITEPIPE` Template="my_fmt")
  ```

If you write a file, you can use this construct:

```
action(type="ompipe" Pipe=`cat pipenamefile` Template="my_fmt")
```

All of this should look familiar to how bash works.

An actual sample of this in action can be found inside our docker container. This here links to the container's [**rsyslog.conf**](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-docker/blob/master/appliance/alpine/rsyslog.conf).

But you can also look at the rest of the Docker definitions to get the whole picture.